# How to connect multiple TCP IP clients to same server port using c++

Tags: c++, tcpclient

I want to connect 2 clients to same server port using TCP IP. I have use the below code before bind:-
// Reuse already binded socket

```
int reuse=1; 
    setsockopt(m_iSocketId, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(reuse))
```

Comment: I recommend to use boost::asio.

Comment: It is not even clear if that code is from client or server; let alone what the code trying to connect or accept connections does. Normally following the average posix sockets tutorial "just works" so without seeing some more code, only the psychic people here can help you.

Comment: What is your current code doing? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Does these two client are on the same machine?

Answer (score 3):

```
listen(iSocketId, 2);
struct sockaddr clientAddr;
socklen_t length = sizeof(clientAddr);
int firstClientSocket = accept(iSocketId, &clientAddr, &length);
length = sizeof(clientAddr);
int secondClientSocket = accept(iSocketId, &clientAddr, &length);
```

After this code, you will have two client sockets to work with. Note, however that 'accept' function blocks until some client connects. In general, you should use some aync methods (e.g. select) to handle multiple clients.

SO_REUSEADDR is generally not intended for your purposes. It just tells the system that the listening port can be reused by multiple instances of the server. It's good for debugging, when your app doesn't close the socket properly upon exit. Otherwise the system might hold the port for some time, refusing to bind another socket to it.

And don't forget error handling on listen and accept calls =)

Comment: You can't call `listen()` twice on the same socket. If your code had proper error checking it would detect an error at the second call. -1

Comment: Right. Sorry for that. listen function indicates the intent to accept incoming connections.

Comment: Is the second `length = sizeof(clientAddr);` call necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `SO_REUSEADDR` for this. You don't need to do anything special. Just create and connect as many sockets in the client as you need, and keep calling `accept()` in the server.